# Spring Kafka Error Handler how to avoid endless loop

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I hope someone can give me a hint want I'm doing wrong here. I wrote a custom error handler for a batch listener that should seek behind the received records, send them to a dlq. I tired a lot but dont get it working. My current implementation will hang in a endless loop receiving the records over and over again. Here the error handler code:

```
@Service("consumerAwareListenerErrorHandlerImpl")
public class ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandlerImpl implements ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler {


    private final Executor executor;

    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;


    @Autowired
    public ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandlerImpl(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry, TaskScheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        this.registry = registry;
    }


    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {

        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        List<String> topics = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, List.class);
        List<Integer> partitions = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, List.class);
        List<Long> offsets = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, List.class);
        Acknowledgment acknowledgment = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);


        Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsetsToReset = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++) {
            int index = i;
            offsetsToReset.compute(new TopicPartition(topics.get(i), partitions.get(i)),
                    (k, v) -> (v == null) ? offsets.get(index) : Math.max(v, offsets.get(index)));
        }
        offsetsToReset.forEach((k, v) -> consumer.seek(k, v));

        if (!(exception.getCause() instanceof DeserializationException)) {
            //pauseAndRestartContainer();
        }

        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        consumer.commitSync();

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to seek to offset+1 to get "past". Seeking to `offset` will cause it to be replayed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I also have the problem, that the error hanlde does not get called when a deserialization exception occurs.
Sure I can use ErrorHandlingDeserializer and manully filter faulty records but that does not help me. I try to:
Serializaiton exception: log; seek past; keep going;
Other Exception: pause; shedule restart; try again
YOu have any idea how to solve this for a batch listener?

Comment: We added the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` (...2 is better than the first one because it is type safe) for exactly this reason. The problem is the deserialization exceptions occur before Spring gets the data so there is nothing else we can do.

Comment: But I still have to filter them in the conainer as it seems?!

Comment: Yes, when using a Batch listener; however, it's more convenient now because the value is type-safe (either `null` or a dummy deserialized object if you provide a `failedDeserializationFunction`). When using a record-based listener, the failed record is sent directly to the container's error handler.

Comment: One more question Gary Russel: If I use ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 the sender needs to use the same class to send the json to my container listener. Else I get "org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name". If I dont use the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 the sender can send any json, if it is compatible with the target dto it get deserialized without any exception. Do you have any hint for me how to solve this?

Comment: Ok, I found out I could do this using;         props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);